# How to use the url hash to load a particular page after a refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I am using url hashes that helps me to bring particular content up on `hashchange`. Now when i'm on some particular content and i refresh the whole page, i'm having that hash in the url and still not getting the content indicated by that hash.

Say my url is :
`http://localhost/user` and i clicked on details and it turned my url into following :
`http://localhost/user#!details`and i'm having the details page.

But having the above as my url when i reload the page, the hash remains same and there is no change in hash which does not invoke the function that i've bind with the hashchange event.

Also i cannot get the hash to the server side without sending ajax request everytime a user reloads using `beforeunload`.

Any Suggestions?

My code :

```
var pages = {};
pages['home'] = ""; pages['details'] = ""; pages['reviews'] = ""; pages['favs'] = "";
pages['likes'] = "", pages['gallery'] = "", pages['visited'] = "", pages['coupons'] = "";

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(event) {
    var curr_hash = event.target.location.hash;
    var page_to_load = curr_hash.substr(2);
    var loadurl = "/ci_theyaw/user/user_" + page_to_load;
    load_page(loadurl, page_to_load);
});

function load_page(page, toload){

    // alert(pages[toload]);

    if(pages[toload] == "") {
        var post_data = {
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: page,
            data: post_data,
            dataType: "html",
            success : function(data) {
                page[toload] = data;
                $('.right-pane').html(data);
            },
            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }

    else {
        $('.right-pane').html(page[toload]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you still using hashbangs? We have [pushState and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) now.

Comment: Gotta take a look at that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run the code attached to `hashchange` on load, in case someone refreshes the page, or even types it directly in to the browser. Try this:

```
var hashUpdate = function(curr_hash) {
    var page_to_load = curr_hash.substr(2);
    var loadurl = "/ci_theyaw/user/user_" + page_to_load;
    load_page(loadurl, page_to_load);
}

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e) {
    hashUpdate(e.target.location.hash);
}); 
window.location.hash && hashUpdate(window.location.hash); // onload, if there was a fragment in the URL
```

Comment: Yeah that worked! Thanks. And could you also tell me that why my browser makes another request to server if at first time i'm storing the data in the page variable and loading it from there?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var curr_hash = window.location.hash;
    var page_to_load = curr_hash.substr(2);
    var loadurl = "/ci_theyaw/user/user_" + page_to_load;
    load_page(loadurl, page_to_load);
});
```